# ReactsJs declaring global variables and change their values inside an if statement

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hi I'm developing an application using react. And I want to check if my user already exists or no.

this how I check if the  user exists

```
var userExists=false 

getProfile((err, profile) => {
    var userId=profile.sub.substring(6,profile.sub.length)
    console.log(userId)
    axios.get('http://localhost:9000/user/'+userId)
    .then(response =>{
      console.log(userId)
        console.log("getting",response.data) 
        if (response.data.id==userId){
          userExist=true
           console.log(userExist)
        }
        else{
          console.log(response.data)
          console.log()

        }
    })  

}) 

console.log(userExist)
```

it always shows me false at the end,  (outside the if tests) .
My question is: how to define a global variable and change it's value when  applying changes ( even inside the if else tests) ?

Comment: Use redux and redux-thunk. The user information can be part of your application/component state.

Comment: there is not another solution ?

Comment: Sure but I don't see why you would opt for another solution. How are you managing application state? Are you writing statefull components with setState?

Comment: no it's  a stateless component

Comment: Then the component needs props to see if user exist and such, that is best managed with redux. Since some of the state management is asynchronous you can use redux-thunk. You can of course come up with your own way of doing it with mutating global variables but that would not be a good idea.

Comment: This is not related to redux at all. The problem is, that axios requests are asynchronous. So by the time you log your global variable the request did not finish leaving `userExists` in its initial state which is `false`. You need to handle requests callback based. This has nothing to do with redux. It's not even related with react.

Answer (score 0):

use can use `window` object.

Example:

```
window.userExists=false
foo()=>{
   window.userExists=true
}
foo()
```